# Packages cannot be nested - as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to use a ActionScript DataGrid component from the mxml file.
But it is showing me some error.

Following is my main application file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:local="*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">



    <mx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
    </mx:Metadata>


    <mx:Button label="Button"/>
    <mx:Array id="arr">
            <mx:Object From="Phill" Subject="GMC-1 Release" Date="12/08/06" CC="Jim"  Profit="69" />
            <mx:Object From="Harry" Subject="GMC-1 Release" Date="12/08/06 11111111" CC="Ram"  Profit="10" />
            <mx:Object From="Barb" Subject="GMC-1 Release" Date="12/08/06" CC="Anant"  Profit="20" />
            <mx:Object From="Amit" Subject="GMC-1 Release" Date="12/07/06" CC="Jim"  Profit="28" />
            <mx:Object From="Sam" Subject="GMC-1 Release" Date="12/08/06" CC="Jim"  Profit="17" />
            <mx:Object From="Phill" Subject="GMC-2 Release" Date="12/11/06" CC="Jim" Profit="10" />
            <mx:Object From="John" Subject="Grid scrolling" Date="12/10/06" CC="Craig" Profit="20" />
            <mx:Object From="Bob" Subject="ItemRenderers" Date="12/10/06" CC="Moxie" Profit="11" />            
</mx:Array>

<local:AutoResizableADG id="adg" dataProvider="{arr}" width="400" height="400" >
    <local:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="From" dataField="From" width="50" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Subject" dataField="Subject" width="50" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Date" dataField="Date" width="70" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="CC" dataField="CC" />
    </local:columns>

</local:AutoResizableADG>

</mx:Application>
```

and the `AutoResizableADG.as` file is in same package .. i.e src/(default-package)

```
// ActionScript file

package     // Line where it is showing error.
{

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;

    import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer;
    import mx.core.IUIComponent;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class AutoResizableADG extends AdvancedDataGrid
    {
        var sepArray:Array = new Array();
        public function AutoResizableADG()
        {
            // call super
            super();
        }

        /**
         *  Returns the header separators between column headers, 
         *  and populates the <code>separators</code> Array with the separators returned.
         * 
         *  @param i The number of separators to return.
         *
         *  @param seperators Array to be populated with the header objects.
         *
         *  @param headerLines The parent component of the header separators. 
         *  Flex calls the <code>headerLines.getChild()</code> method internally to return the separators.
         */
        override protected function getSeparator(i:int, seperators:Array, headerLines:UIComponent):UIComponent
        {

            var sep:UIComponent = super.getSeparator(i, seperators, headerLines);
            sep.doubleClickEnabled = true;
            // Add listener for Double Click
            DisplayObject(sep).addEventListener(myEvent.myEvent, hello);
            //          Alert.show(""+sep);
            sepArray.push(sep);
            return sep;
        }

        public function getListItems():Array{
            return listItems;
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         *  Indicates where the right side of a resized column appears.
         */
        public function hello(event:UIComponent):void
        {
            // check if the ADG is enabled and the columns are resizable
            if (!enabled || !resizableColumns)
                return;

            var target:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event);
            var index:int = target.parent.getChildIndex(target);
            // get the columns array
            var optimumColumns:Array = getOptimumColumns();

            // check for resizable column
            if (!optimumColumns[index].resizable)
                return;

            // calculate the maxWidth - we can optimize this calculation
            if(listItems)
            {
                var len:int = listItems.length;
                var maxWidth:int = 0;
                for(var i:int=0;i<len;i++)
                {
                    if(listItems[i][index] is IDropInListItemRenderer)
                    {
                        var lineMetrics:TextLineMetrics = measureText(IDropInListItemRenderer(listItems[i][index]).listData.label);
                        if(lineMetrics.width > maxWidth)
                            maxWidth = lineMetrics.width ;
                    }
                }
            }

            // set the column's width
            optimumColumns[index].width = maxWidth + getStyle("paddingLeft") + getStyle("paddingRight") + 8;
        }
    }
}
```

---

It is showing me the error in ActionScript file ....

```
"Packages cannot be nested"
```

Why is this happening ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Your code seems correct - I've copied and pasted it to my editor and no "Packages cannot be nested" error was shown.  Could it be related to your folder structure (no-name package is always the top source folder)?  What about the super class?  Which IDE are you using?  If you're in Flash Builder or FDT, try `Project -> Clean`.

Comment: I just set up a new project using only your code. I got a compile error for the AutoResizableADG class, saying that 'myEvent' was an undefined property, is this your problem? The only code I have is your class and the application code above, all in the default package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not compiling, but have you tried putting AutoResizableADG.as into an actual package to see if it fixes the problem?

E.g.

```
// ActionScript file

package myPackage
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;

import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer;
import mx.core.IUIComponent;
import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class AutoResizableADG extends AdvancedDataGrid
{
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's behavior that I call quirky, but documented. I found two fixes:

1. weltraumpirat's correct. try cleaning your code.
2. if you are in flashdevelop, you can delete the myPackge reference,
   test the project again, and when it says the next error, undo the
   change and it will accept it.

Both methods operate under the same principle.
good luck!